# JAVA: How to listen to calling of event handler/How to get returned result of an event handler?

Tags: java, android, event-handling, java-websocket

I am creating an Android chat application wherein I am using WebSockets and on top of that I want to create a custom implementation of Application protocol.

I am stuck in a situation.

Essentially, what I want is a way to know that an event handler method has been called in another class, fire up my own method in my class based on that and then get the result of that event handler method in my class.

How is that possible?

I researched a lot and found something like binding, event emitters, etc. Can someone point me to the right direction and provide some resources from where I can learn this technique?

This is what I have done so far:

```
public void connect(){

        try {

            setUpWebSocketHandler(handler);
           mConnection.connect(wsuri, handler);

        }
        catch (WebSocketException e) {

           Log.d("exception", e.toString());
        }


}


public void setUpWebSocketHandler(WebSocketHandler handler)
{
    handler = new WebSocketHandler(){

  //first method for websockethandler

        @Override
        public void onOpen() {


            //here i create a json format string to be sent to my         server that returns something afterwards
            String output = json.toString();
            Log.d("OUTPUT+" , output);
            Log.d("onOpen", "Status: Connected to " + wsuri);
            mConnection.sendTextMessage(output);
        }



//second method for websockethandler
        @Override
        public void onTextMessage(final String payload) {

            Log.d("onTextMessage", "Response: " + payload);
            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(payload);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {

                String type = jsonObj.getString("type");
                switch (type) {
                    case "xxx":
                        //authEvent
                        System.out.println("xxx");
                        break;
                    case "yyy":
                        //userOnlineEvent
                        System.out.println("yyy");
                        break;
                    case "zzz":
                        System.out.println("zzz");

                        break;
                    case "userListToken":

                        userList = getUserList(payload);

                        break;


                    default:
                        System.out.println("DefaultCase");
                        break;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }

//third method for websockethandler

        @Override
        public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
            Log.d("onClose", "Connection lost.");
        }

    };
}



public String getUserList(final String payload)
{
    final Thread connectthread;
    connectthread = new Thread(
            new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                        //here i create a URL, send post request to it and i get a response with userlist
                        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                        HttpGet post = new HttpGet(url);


                        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));


                        while ((userList = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(userList);
                            Log.d("HTTP GET RESPONSE", "Response: " + userList);

                        }



                    } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    );



    connectthread.start();
    try
    {
        connectthread.join();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("error","Error!!");
    }

    System.out.println("userListToken");
    return userList;
}
```

I have another question. I got the userList using callbacks....The problem now is:

```
private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String uname,password;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        uname = txtUsername.getText().toString();
        password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String user = null;

        ifly.connect();


        user = userList;
        return user;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String user) {
        try {

            if(user != null){






                //Intent i = new Intent("com.example.tabmainactivity");
                Log.d("Got it", "Response: " + userList);
                pDialog.dismiss();
                //startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),iFlyChatMessage.class));
                //startActivity(i);
                //finish();

            }else{
                // username / password doesn't match
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Incorrect username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


public void processMessage(String userList)
{
       this.userList = userList;
}
```

I want the userList in postExecute so that i can send this userList to another activity. How do i stop doinbackground() to wait for callback to finish. If I use thread.sleep, the whole process stops, not even connect works.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of what you tried so far/ what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JohannisK I have included the code. Now I want the userList string in my activity whenever the method onTextMessage is called. It will be great if you can point to me the resources where I can learn event binding, emitting, subscribing, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood you correctly.

You should use callback object.

Something like:

```
public interface MessageProcesor{
         public void processMessage(String message);
     }
```

Your activity should implement this interface.
And you should have `MessageProcesor` field in your "client" class.
Your code should look something like this:

```
private MessageProcesor callback;

public void setUpWebSocketHandler(WebSocketHandler handler)
{
    handler = new WebSocketHandler(){

  //first method for websockethandler

        @Override
        public void onOpen() {


            //here i create a json format string to be sent to my         server that returns something afterwards
            String output = json.toString();
            Log.d("OUTPUT+" , output);
            Log.d("onOpen", "Status: Connected to " + wsuri);
            mConnection.sendTextMessage(output);
        }



//second method for websockethandler
        @Override
        public void onTextMessage(final String payload) {

            Log.d("onTextMessage", "Response: " + payload);
            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(payload);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {

                String type = jsonObj.getString("type");
                switch (type) {
                    case "xxx":
                        //authEvent
                        System.out.println("xxx");
                        break;
                    case "yyy":
                        //userOnlineEvent
                        System.out.println("yyy");
                        break;
                    case "zzz":
                        System.out.println("zzz");

                        break;
                    case "userListToken":

                        userList = getUserList(payload);
                        callback.processMessage(userList);

                        break;


                    default:
                        System.out.println("DefaultCase");
                        break;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }

//third method for websockethandler

        @Override
        public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
            Log.d("onClose", "Connection lost.");
        }

    };
}



public String getUserList(final String payload)
{
    final Thread connectthread;
    connectthread = new Thread(
            new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                        //here i create a URL, send post request to it and i get a response with userlist
                        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                        HttpGet post = new HttpGet(url);


                        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));


                        while ((userList = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(userList);
                            Log.d("HTTP GET RESPONSE", "Response: " + userList);

                        }



                    } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    );



    connectthread.start();
    try
    {
        connectthread.join();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("error","Error!!");
    }

    System.out.println("userListToken");
    return userList;
}
```

You can pass "callback" as constructor param or via setter method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please help me through one more problem?....I have edited my question for the second problem.

Comment: @kerry, sorry, don't understand the problem. You need to wait for userList will be initialized to for using it in onPostExecute?
Can you post more code? I can't understand how your ProcessLogin work.

Comment: Actually, that's all the code. I'll explain. After I click on the button login, the asynctask starts. In doinBackground() method, the ifly.connect() starts the method to connect (the first code). This connect method generated the userlist and call backs to the activity where asynctask started. But while the connect thing gets userlist, the asynctask has already completed the postexecute. I just want it to wait till I get a callback so that I get the userlist in the postexecute. Thanks for ur time.

Comment: Looks like your architecture completely wrong.
Because username will be set only after the onTextMessage with the userListToken type.
Looks like you should use Handler class. To send messages to your Activities from client. If you don't post all the code it's hard to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76512/discussion-between-andrey-e-and-kerry).

Comment: Hey Andrey, I actually solved the problem. Just changed the execution of my asynctask. Made it after i get the userlist using broadcast receiver. Thank you so much for your time. Appreciate that!!

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an interface somewhere, make your event handler accept an instance of this interface, then create an anonymous class implementing this interface while passing that instance in your handler's registration with event source.

Something like below:

`public class MyClass{
...
...
    component.addXXXListener(new EventHandler(new MyInterface() {
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            callMethod();
        }
    }));
...
...
    public void callMethod() {
    ...
    ... 
    }`

I hope you got the point.

Comment: Actually, I am quite new to JAVA. Will it be possible for you to have a look at my code and let me know, how can I retrieve the userlist from the onTextMessage method in my activity somewhere else (if in my activity, I run connect()?